# I can't connect to localhost from other computers

Tags: networking, server, permissions, remote-access, localhost

I can see the web pages I created in `/var/www/html/` by typing `localhost` in URL bar.

A few months ago I could even access those pages by typing my ip address from other computers,
but now I am getting server timed out when I type my ip address from my mobile phone;
my friends are also not able to connect by typing my ip address.

Recently I installed webmin from [a tutorial in unixmen](http://www.unixmen.com/install-webmin-ubuntu-14-04/),
I thought maybe it changed read and execute permissions. so I executed the command `chmod -R 775`,
but it didn't change anything (still not able to connect from other computers).

Everything is working fine from host computer.

The output of `ifconfig` is:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:9e:01:00:10:ad  
          inet addr:183.83.83.29  Bcast:183.83.127.255  Mask:255.255.192.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a9e:1ff:fe00:10ad/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:443584 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:378897 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:470991396 (470.9 MB)  TX bytes:96527317 (96.5 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:154813 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:154813 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:20729684 (20.7 MB)  TX bytes:20729684 (20.7 MB)

pan1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 42:dd:4f:ed:a2:f2  
          inet addr:10.141.41.1  Bcast:10.141.41.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::40dd:4fff:feed:a2f2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:174 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:32909 (32.9 KB)
```

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your ISP, internet service provider. Do you pay for a static IP? If not, then it is probably because it had changed, and is now accessible from that new ip. Could you edit your question to include all of the output from executing `ifconfig` in terminal, and visit [this](http://iplemon.com) website and tell us what it says.

Comment: Go to http://www.canyouseeme.org/ on the server and check if your port 80 is open

Comment: Are we talking about access over a LAN or the internet?

Comment: From canyouseeme.org I got "Error: I could not see your service on 183.83.83.29 on port (80)
Reason: Connection timed out" @meccooll

Comment: access over internet @dan08

Comment: Thanks for replying, my IP is not static but I checked with the current IP, iplemon.com gives my IP address.

Comment: Unless you blocked it yourself ( set up a firewall ) then your ISP is probably blocking it.  Try changing the server to listen on a port above 1024 instead of 80.

Comment: Same with 1024 'connection timed out', do you think its because of firewall? How to know, and change the settings?

Comment: Thank you everyone, I think it was the firewall, by disabling the firewall with the command
        
'sudo ufw disable'
        
I could open the index page from mobile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you everyone, I think it was the firewall, by disabling the firewall as given in the site https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/firewall.html with the command:

`sudo ufw disable`

I could open the index page from mobile.

Comment: I wonder what security problems you have opened up, watch /var/log/auth.log http://serverfault.com/questions/244614/is-it-normal-to-get-hundreds-of-break-in-attempts-per-day

Comment: this "ufw" thing never worked for me, not matter what. Im using ubuntu 18. May be it helps other, for me it finally worked via  "Firewall" ubuntu GUI application.

Comment: This answer saved me 5 hours